# Manwah about a holy lady transmigrating/reincarnating into a villainess

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

In the story, the holy lady is dying, because her life is up. As soon as she closes her eyes, she wishes that all of the people who followed her can live happy lives. When she wakes up, she is a wife of a nobleman. I’m pretty sure that he was a duke. He has a son who has been sick. Since she has become the stepmother, she still has her healing powers from when she was the holy lady. She heals the son without telling the husband because she plans to divorce him. Because he doesn’t love her.  the original owner of the body tricked the husband into marrying her by telling him that she could help his son. I haven’t got really far in the story. But the husband is starting to realize that the wife does a lot for him and his household. And so now he’s starting to treat her with respect and starting to fall in love. Also people from her past, as the holy lady shows up in her new life. Because they are somewhat attracted to her, because they feel the aura of when she was a holy lady. Those people being the prince, but now the emperor and one of the knights that she thought with.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any characters?

Comment: "knights that she thought with"?

Comment: Most likely "fought with". Do you recall how the protagonist died in her first life? I'm guessing old age, but that isn't specified. You mention "transmigration", but this is same-world reincarnation, correct? Do you remember when you read this, and about how many chapters there were? Do you remember the appearance of any of the characters? How old was the stepson? Baby? Child? Teenager? Adult?

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Everybody Loves the Villainess](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/everybody-loves-the-villainess)*. It is licensed by [Pocket Comics](https://www.pocketcomics.com/comic/8164?languageCode=en).

> **High priest Sia awaits her peaceful death after leading a life devoted to helping other people**. Instead of finding herself next to Lord Pleon the God, she finds herself in the body of Elena, a woman known to be wicked. While adjusting to her new body and new life as a universally hated figure, **Sia continues to encounter men she had acquainted during her day as a high priest**. What's even more surprising is that those men seem to get increasingly obsessed with her. "I am no longer the high priest on whom everyone depended, so why are these men still getting obsessed with me?!"

The synopsis covers most of the details of the question. The story opens with the main character, a powerful priest, on her deathbed.

[image: On her deathbed, wishes everyone happiness]

She dies, and finds herself in the body of a wicked woman. This woman claimed she had holy powers that could heal the man's son, but this was a lie to gain his affection.

[image: Lies to gain affection]

After reincarnating, she visits the son and cures him of his illness uses her divine powers.