# Looking for a manwha of a saintess that is reborn in another body

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, reincarnation

i forgot the name of a manwha i was reading. Basically, the MC is a saintess really powerful and loved by some followers, but she eventually dies after healing a guy and her soul gets reborn as a noble woman that is married and has a son. If i remember correctly one of the guys that knew her as a saintess recognizes that she is reborn and tries to approach her in the new body. She has all of her memories and can use healing powers, i remember that the og noblewoman lied to her husband that she could heal their son but when MC entered her body she actually healed the kid and asked for him to keep it a secret. She doesn't want people to know she is the saintess soul cause if they find out she might have to go to the temple/church in this life. I don't remember much more details, if you can help me i'll be realy grateful. Thank you <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be ***[Everybody Loves the Villainess](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/everybody-loves-the-villainess)***.

From Anime-Planet:

> High priest Sia awaits her peaceful death after leading a life devoted to helping other people. Instead of finding herself next to Lord Pleon the God, she finds herself in the body of Elena, a woman known to be wicked. While adjusting to her new body and new life as a universally hated figure, Sia continues to encounter men she had acquainted during her day as a high priest. What's even more surprising is that those men seem to get increasingly obsessed with her. "I am no longer the high priest on whom everyone depended, so why are these men still getting obsessed with me?!"

A high priestess, Lady Sia Elbrade, dies after using her powers to heal Phael, a loyal knight who served under her. She then wakes up inside the adult body of a duchess, Elena Lopherson.

Elena was known as the most wicked woman of her time and had lied to her husband about having the ability to heal his sick son, in order to convince him to marry her. After waking up in Elena's body, Sia uses her powers to heal the boy, but tells him to keep it a secret, as she doesn't want anyone to come looking for her.

She later encounters Phael, who overheard something she said and recognised it as something previously said by Sia.

Comment: Also the unaccepted answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268754/manwah-about-a-holy-lady-transmigrating-reincarnating-into-a-villainess/268894#268894